# Beeware Toga WebView widget TypeError

Tags: python, webview, pycairo, beeware

I'm trying to run the [beeware](https://beeware.org) tutorial.

When adding a [toga.WebView](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/widgets/webview.html) I get the following error message when running `briefcase run -u`:

```
** (__main__.py:25869): WARNING **: 16:57:29.287: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37' referenced by the typelib: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: cairo_font_options_set_variations
/tmp/.mount_fubar0Ml5JP/usr/app_packages/toga_gtk/widgets/webview.py:21: Warning: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type 'void'
  self.webview = WebKit2.WebView()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/.mount_fubar0Ml5JP/usr/app_packages/toga_gtk/app.py", line 93, in gtk_startup
    self.interface.startup()
  File "/tmp/.mount_fubar0Ml5JP/usr/app/fubarr/app.py", line 32, in startup
    song=toga.WebView(url="https://stackoverflow.com")
  File "/tmp/.mount_fubar0Ml5JP/usr/app_packages/toga/widgets/webview.py", line 28, in __init__
    self._impl = self.factory.WebView(interface=self)
  File "/tmp/.mount_fubar0Ml5JP/usr/app_packages/toga_gtk/widgets/base.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.create()
  File "/tmp/.mount_fubar0Ml5JP/usr/app_packages/toga_gtk/widgets/webview.py", line 21, in create
    self.webview = WebKit2.WebView()
TypeError: could not get a reference to type class
```

What I tried so far:

- downgrade pycairo to 1.11.1
- just run `import toga; toga.WebView(url="https://stackoverflow.com")` within the virtualenv.. which works
- web search
- pray to the spaghetti monster

I am using ubuntu 19.10 and python 3.7.5.

Thanks for any hint.